# SQL Server Resource database and DMOs

Tags: sql-server

I have several questions I cannot find definite answers for:

1) A quick googling about DMOs returns quite a few articles that state that those DMOs reside in master database.

I understand that they are actually defined in mssqlsystenresource.mdf resource database.

But how does this reconcile with the fact that DMVs (not DMFs) appear in every single database?  What is the underlying difference, if any,  when DMVs are used under different database context?

My understanding is if the view / stored procedure returns system-wide information (server-scoped), it shouldn't matter where they are executed, as long as the users have the appropriate privileges. And if they turn out to be database-scoped, it is even logical that each database should contain its own copies of definitions for DMVs.

2) About DMFs

2.a)   `sys.dm_` and `sys.fn_` functions, which are also defined in resource database, only appear in system databases. they cannot be found inside any user database. But they are perfectly usable within user databases.

4.b) *Regular* system functions, such as `Aggregate` and `String` functions, also defined in the resource database, appear in any user database, but not in any of the system database, not even in `model`, which is supposed to be a model. Yet again, the functions I tested worked fine in those system databases.

Can anyone help me with how all these are organized?

Thanks for any help.